# R, conditional cumulative sum to an maximum value

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

```
df <- data.frame("day" = 1:20, 
                   "LATP"= c(.08,.11,.12,.09,.14,.06,.10,.11,.13,.08,.15,.08,.11,.14,.08,.11,.14,.07,.11,.12), 
                   "LATP2"  = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0))
```

Here is a sample dataframe. I am trying to cumulative sum the values in the LATP column until a maximum of 1, based on whether a binary function in LATP2 (= 1),  has been triggered. I need to make a cumulative sum each time the binary function is triggered, even when they overlap. I guess it would be best to make a new subset dataframe that will bring over the range of LATP values necessary to reach 1 and then can be grouped by the binary event that started them? I would like to be able to graph the progress of the cumulative LATP for each event.

This is a subset of a grapevine Powdery Mildew disease pressure model dataframe, The LATP is the latency progression from primary infection to secondary infection being fully established. So each spore release (LATP2) event will have a its own latency period that is the sum of the latency progression.

I would provide some attempts, but I don't really know where to start with this problem

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

We create a grouping index based on the run-length-encoding-id of 'LATP2' and get the cumulative sum of 'LATP'

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
    group_by(grp = lag(rleid(LATP2), default = 1)) %>% 
    mutate(new = cumsum(LATP))
# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   grp [9]
#     day  LATP LATP2   grp   new
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  0.08     0     1  0.08
# 2     2  0.11     0     1  0.19
# 3     3  0.12     0     1  0.31
# 4     4  0.09     1     1  0.4 
# 5     5  0.14     0     2  0.14
# 6     6  0.06     0     3  0.06
# 7     7  0.1      0     3  0.16
# 8     8  0.11     1     3  0.27
# 9     9  0.13     1     4  0.13
#10    10  0.08     0     4  0.21
#11    11  0.15     0     5  0.15
#12    12  0.08     0     5  0.23
#13    13  0.11     0     5  0.34
#14    14  0.14     1     5  0.48
#15    15  0.08     0     6  0.08
#16    16  0.11     0     7  0.11
#17    17  0.14     0     7  0.25
#18    18  0.07     1     7  0.32
#19    19  0.11     0     8  0.11
#20    20  0.12     0     9  0.12
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this is very close to what im hoping to do. Im looking to have the cumsum start after a 1 in the LATP2 column. The trick i think is in having the cumsum continue to count even though a new group might need to be counted from the same LATP value. Does this make sense?

Comment: @AndrewWatts Can you update your post with the expected output column so that I can crossmatch it